# iOS OpenTok - How to style the video views?

Tags: ios, view, video-streaming, styling

I am using the OpenTok iOS Framework to allow video chat within my app.
However, I am trying to find a way to custom style the views that display the user and connected user's streams.
From what I have found, it seems like these views are created in OTVideoView files, but I can only access the header.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to customize the views for the streams so I can make it look nicer than the default styling?

Comment: Could you more clearly define what you mean by custom styles? Are you trying to disable the buttons? Are you trying to remove the name bar? I am the product manager working on the iOS SDK, and so I'm just trying to get the necessary feedback to help answer the question correctly (and potentially understand if an enhancement is being requested as well).

Answer (score 1):

Hi, Each Subscriber.view of publisher.view is really a UIView object (Technical talk: OTVideoView is subclass of UIView). You can style them however you like by applying transforms and such to the view.

For example, to adjust width/height dynamically, you can do something like this:
[_publisher.view setFrame:CGRectMake(left, top, width, height)];

Anything you can do to UIView, you can do with OTVideoView. 
Here's UIView's documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Hope that helps,
Song

P.S. If you have time, check out this blog post about using Core Graphics with OpenTok's video streams to do some nifty image recognition! 
http://www.tokbox.com/blog/fun-with-core-graphics-in-ios/